# KL divergence between two multivariate Gaussians

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, kullback-leibler

I'm having trouble deriving the KL divergence formula assuming two multivariate normal distributions. I've done the univariate case fairly easily. However, it's been quite a while since I took math stats, so I'm having some trouble extending it to the multivariate case. I'm sure I'm just missing something simple.

Here's what I have...

Suppose both $p$ and $q$ are the pdfs of normal distributions with means $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ and variances $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$, respectively.
The Kullback-Leibler distance from $q$ to $p$ is:

$\int \left[\log( p(x)) - \log( q(x)) \right]\ p(x)\ dx$, 
which for two multivariate normals is:

$\frac{1}{2}\left[\log\frac{|\Sigma_2|}{|\Sigma_1|} - d + Tr(\Sigma_2^{-1}\Sigma_1) + (\mu_2 - \mu_1)^T \Sigma_2^{-1}(\mu_2 - \mu_1)\right]$

Following the same logic as [this proof](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7440/kl-divergence-between-two-univariate-gaussians), I get to about here before I get stuck:

$=\int \left[ \frac{d}{2} \log\frac{|\Sigma_2|}{|\Sigma_1|} + \frac{1}{2} \left((x-\mu_2)^T\Sigma_2^{-1}(x-\mu_2) - (x-\mu_1)^T\Sigma_2^{-1}(x-\mu_1) \right) \right] \times p(x) dx$

$=\mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{d}{2} \log\frac{|\Sigma_2|}{|\Sigma_1|} + \frac{1}{2} \left((x-\mu_2)^T\Sigma_2^{-1}(x-\mu_2) - (x-\mu_1)^T\Sigma_2^{-1}(x-\mu_1) \right) \right]$

I think I have to implement the [trace trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_of_covariance_matrices#The_trace_of_a_1_.C3.97_1_matrix), but I'm just not sure what to do after that. Any helpful hints to put me back on the right track would be appreciated!

Comment: http://stanford.edu/~jduchi/projects/general_notes.pdf. The last section also gives the derivation.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Starting with where you began with some slight corrections, we can write

$$
\begin{aligned}
KL &= \int \left[ \frac{1}{2} \log\frac{|\Sigma_2|}{|\Sigma_1|} - \frac{1}{2} (x-\mu_1)^T\Sigma_1^{-1}(x-\mu_1) + \frac{1}{2} (x-\mu_2)^T\Sigma_2^{-1}(x-\mu_2) \right] \times p(x) dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \log\frac{|\Sigma_2|}{|\Sigma_1|} - \frac{1}{2} \text{tr}\ \left\{E[(x - \mu_1)(x - \mu_1)^T] \ \Sigma_1^{-1} \right\} + \frac{1}{2} E[(x - \mu_2)^T \Sigma_2^{-1} (x - \mu_2)] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \log\frac{|\Sigma_2|}{|\Sigma_1|} - \frac{1}{2} \text{tr}\ \{I_d \} + \frac{1}{2} (\mu_1 - \mu_2)^T \Sigma_2^{-1} (\mu_1 - \mu_2) + \frac{1}{2} \text{tr} \{ \Sigma_2^{-1} \Sigma_1 \} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[\log\frac{|\Sigma_2|}{|\Sigma_1|} - d + \text{tr} \{ \Sigma_2^{-1}\Sigma_1 \} + (\mu_2 - \mu_1)^T \Sigma_2^{-1}(\mu_2 - \mu_1)\right].
\end{aligned}
$$

Note that I have used a couple of properties from [Section 8.2 of the Matrix Cookbook](http://orion.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf).

Comment: I see you took out the D that I had originally. Wouldn't you have a D term after taking the log of the Gaussian in the first few steps?

Comment: Consider the scaling factor $(2\pi)^{-d/2} |\Sigma_k|^{-1/2}$, $k = 1,2$ of the multivariate normal density. When computing the log-difference, the $(2\pi)^{-d/2}$ term goes away. There is no $d$ term for the determinants -- simply, a $1/2$, which is factored out.

Comment: Hi, how did you come up with the last step? How did you change sign of $\mu_1 - \mu_2$ into $\mu_2 - \mu_1$?

Comment: @acidghost Either one works because we can factor out a negative one from both sides. Multiplying the two negative ones yields a positive one.

Comment: @JohnA.Ramey. Which property of the sec 8.2 you used? Is it eq. 380 ? If yes, I'm not able to follow, Can you explain?

Comment: @chandresh Use eq. 377 to simplify the second expression on line 2. Use eq. 380 to simplify the last expression on line 2.

Comment: I would still recommend https://stanford.edu/~jduchi/projects/general_notes.pdf page 13. Much easier to follow.