# KL divergence between two bivariate Gaussian distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, kullback-leibler, bivariate

[KL divergence between two multivariate Gaussians](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60680/kl-divergence-between-two-multivariate-gaussians) and [univariate Gaussians](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7440/kl-divergence-between-two-univariate-gaussians) have been discussed. I was wondering if there exists a simpler computation for the KL divergence between two bivariate Gaussians in terms of their [means, variances and correlation coefficient](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BivariateNormalDistribution.html) without using the more general multivariate form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have for two $d$ dimensional multivariaiate Gaussian distributions $P = \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ and $Q = \mathcal{N}(m, S)$ that

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}
  \mathbb{D}_{\textrm{KL}}(P \Vert Q) = 
  \frac{1}{2} \left( 
    \tr(S^{-1}\Sigma) - d + 
    (m - \mu)S^{-1}(m-\mu) + 
    \log\frac{|S|}{|\Sigma|}
  \right).
$$

For the bivariate case i.e. $d=2$, parameterising in terms of the component means, standard deviations and correlation coefficients we define the mean vectors and covariance matrices as

$$
  \mu = 
  \begin{pmatrix} 
    \mu_1\\ 
    \mu_2 
  \end{pmatrix},~
  \Sigma = 
  \begin{pmatrix} 
    \sigma_1^2 & \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 \\ 
    \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 & \sigma_2^2 
  \end{pmatrix}
  \quad\textrm{and}\quad 
  m = 
  \begin{pmatrix} 
    m_1 \\ 
    m_2 
  \end{pmatrix},~
  S = 
  \begin{pmatrix} 
    s_1^2 & r s_1 s_2 \\ 
    r s_1 s_2 & s_2^2 
  \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Using the definitions of the determinant and inverse of $2\times 2$ matrices we have that

$$
  |\Sigma| = \sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2(1-\rho^2),~
  |S| = s_1^2 s_2^2 (1 - r^2) ~\textrm{and}~
  S^{-1} = 
  \frac{1}{s_1^2 s_2^2 (1 - r^2)} 
  \begin{pmatrix} s_2^2 & -r s_1 s_2 \\ -r s_1 s_2 & s_1^2 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Substituting these terms in to the above and simplifying gives

\begin{align}
  \mathbb{D}_{\textrm{KL}}(P \Vert Q) =  &\,
  \frac{1}{2(1-r^2)} \left(
  \frac{(\mu_1-m_1)^2}{s_1^2} - 2r \frac{(\mu_1-m_1)(\mu_2-m_2)}{s_1 s_2} + \frac{(\mu_2-m_2)^2}{s_2^2}
  \right) +\,\\
  &\, 
  \frac{1}{2(1-r^2)} \left(
  \frac{\sigma_1^2-s_1^2}{s_1^2} - 2r \frac{\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 - r s_1 s_2}{s_1 s_2} + \frac{\sigma_2^2-s_2^2}{s_2^2}
  \right) +\, \\
  &\,
  \log\left( \frac{s_1 s_2 \sqrt{1-r^2}}{\sigma_1\sigma_2\sqrt{1-\rho^2}} \right). 
\end{align}

This [can be verified with SymPy](https://live.sympy.org/?evaluate=d%20%3D%202%0As1%2C%20s2%2C%20r%2C%20m1%2C%20m2%20%3D%20symbols(%27s_1%20s_2%20r%20m_1%20m_2%27)%0Asigma1%2C%20sigma2%2C%20rho%2C%20mu1%2C%20mu2%20%3D%20symbols(r%27%5Csigma_1%20%5Csigma_2%20%5Crho%20%5Cmu_1%20%5Cmu_2%27)%0Am%20%3D%20Matrix(%5Bm1%2C%20m2%5D)%0AS%20%3D%20Matrix(%5B%5Bs1**2%2C%20r*s1*s2%5D%2C%20%5Br*s1*s2%2C%20s2**2%5D%5D)%0Amu%20%3D%20Matrix(%5Bmu1%2C%20mu2%5D)%0ASigma%20%3D%20Matrix(%5B%5Bsigma1**2%2C%20rho*sigma1*sigma2%5D%2C%20%5Brho*sigma1*sigma2%2C%20sigma2**2%5D%5D)%0Alhs%20%3D%20(%0A%20%20%20%20trace(S**(-1)%20*%20Sigma)%20-%20d%20%2B%20%0A%20%20%20%20((m%20-%20mu).T%20*%20S**(-1)%20*%20(m%20-%20mu))%5B0%5D%20%2B%0A%20%20%20%20log(det(S)%20%2F%20det(Sigma))%0A)%20%2F%202%0Arhs%20%3D%20(%0A%20%20%20%20((mu1-m1)**2%2Fs1**2%20-%202*r*(mu1-m1)*(mu2-m2)%2F(s1*s2)%20%2B%20(mu2-m2)**2%2Fs2**2)%20%2F%0A%20%20%20%20(2%20*%20(1%20-%20r**2))%20%2B%0A%20%20%20%20((sigma1**2-s1**2)%2Fs1**2%20-%202*r*(rho*sigma1*sigma2-r*s1*s2)%2F(s1*s2)%20%2B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20(sigma2**2-s2**2)%2Fs2**2)%20%2F%0A%20%20%20%20(2%20*%20(1%20-%20r**2))%20%2B%0A%20%20%20%20log((s1**2%20*%20s2**2%20*%20(1-r**2))%20%2F%20(sigma1**2%20*%20sigma2**2%20*%20(1-rho**2)))%20%2F%202%0A)%0Asimplify(lhs%20-%20rhs)%20%3D%3D%200) as follows

```py
from sympy import *
d = 2
s1, s2, r, m1, m2 = symbols('s_1 s_2 r m_1 m_2')
sigma1, sigma2, rho, mu1, mu2 = symbols(r'\sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho \mu_1 \mu_2')
m = Matrix([m1, m2])
S = Matrix([[s1**2, r*s1*s2], [r*s1*s2, s2**2]])
mu = Matrix([mu1, mu2])
Sigma = Matrix([[sigma1**2, rho*sigma1*sigma2], [rho*sigma1*sigma2, sigma2**2]])
lhs = (
    trace(S**(-1) * Sigma) - d + 
    ((m - mu).T * S**(-1) * (m - mu))[0] +
    log(det(S) / det(Sigma))
) / 2
rhs = (
    ((mu1-m1)**2/s1**2 - 2*r*(mu1-m1)*(mu2-m2)/(s1*s2) + (mu2-m2)**2/s2**2) /
    (2 * (1 - r**2)) +
    ((sigma1**2-s1**2)/s1**2 - 2*r*(rho*sigma1*sigma2-r*s1*s2)/(s1*s2) + 
     (sigma2**2-s2**2)/s2**2) /
    (2 * (1 - r**2)) +
    log((s1**2 * s2**2 * (1-r**2)) / (sigma1**2 * sigma2**2 * (1-rho**2))) / 2
)
simplify(lhs - rhs) == 0
```