# Expectation of multivariate gaussian w.r.t. other multivariate gaussian

Tags: expected-value, multivariate-normal-distribution, kullback-leibler

I want to calculate the Kullbach Leibler Divergence of two multivariate Gaussians as in

[KL divergence between two multivariate Gaussians](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60680/kl-divergence-between-two-multivariate-gaussians?noredirect=1&lq=1).

At one point one has to solve the following expression (which is also equation 380 in the matrix cookbook):

$$ E_q[(x-\mu_1)^T\Sigma_2^{-1}(\mu_1-\mu_2)]$$

where the expectation is taken across another multivariate gaussian 
$$ q(x) = N(\mu_1, \Sigma_1)$$.

And this should evaluate to zero, but I dont understand how and why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $ (x - \mu_1)\Sigma_2^{-1}(\mu_1 - \mu_2)$ is just a linear function of x. You can write it as $(x-b)A$ where $b = \mu_1$ and $A = \Sigma_2^{-1}(\mu_1 - \mu_2)$ are constants.

By linearity of expectation,  $E[(x-b)A] = (E[x] - b)A$. Note that $E[x] = b =\mu_1$ and thus the whole expression is zero.