# Kullback-Leibler divergence between product of independent gaussians and a multivariate normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, kullback-leibler

what's the correct way to quantify the loss of information we have when  we approximate the likelihood from    multivariate normal distribution with a full covariance matrix to a product of univariate Gaussian pdf   ?  I am doing some Bayesian inference and i am comparing the results i get when i use the multivariate distribution with the one i get when i assume the data points independents. The results are very similar but i would like to know if there is some procedure that can justify this approximation.

i have read i can use the Kullback-Leibler divergence

like in [KL divergence between two multivariate Gaussians](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60680/kl-divergence-between-two-multivariate-gaussians)

$$
\begin{aligned}
KL &= \int \left[ \frac{1}{2} \log\frac{|\Sigma_2|}{|\Sigma_1|} - \frac{1}{2} (x-\mu_1)^T\Sigma_1^{-1}(x-\mu_1) + \frac{1}{2} (x-\mu_2)^T\Sigma_2^{-1}(x-\mu_2) \right] \times p(x) dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \log\frac{|\Sigma_2|}{|\Sigma_1|} - \frac{1}{2} \text{tr}\ \left\{E[(x - \mu_1)(x - \mu_1)^T] \ \Sigma_1^{-1} \right\} + \frac{1}{2} E[(x - \mu_2)^T \Sigma_2^{-1} (x - \mu_2)] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \log\frac{|\Sigma_2|}{|\Sigma_1|} - \frac{1}{2} \text{tr}\ \{I_d \} + \frac{1}{2} (\mu_1 - \mu_2)^T \Sigma_2^{-1} (\mu_1 - \mu_2) + \frac{1}{2} \text{tr} \{ \Sigma_2^{-1} \Sigma_1 \} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[\log\frac{|\Sigma_2|}{|\Sigma_1|} - d + \text{tr} \{ \Sigma_2^{-1}\Sigma_1 \} + (\mu_2 - \mu_1)^T \Sigma_2^{-1}(\mu_2 - \mu_1)\right].
\end{aligned}
$$

is it correct if i reduce this solution for 2 multivariate Gaussian in the solution i want by considering $\Sigma_2$ as a diagonal matrix ?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "product of gaussian distributions"?  What kind of gaussian (univariate, multivariate) and what kind of product (Cartesian; product of densities; product of CDFS; product of random variables)?

Comment: product of univariate gaussian pdf

Comment: Okay.  But since that is explicitly answered in the thread you reference, please tell us what specifically you need help with. In particular, you need to explain what $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ represent.

Comment: @whuber no it isn't written there, i read it on chatgpt. in that thread there is only the formula to calculate the kl divergence between 2 multivariate. Since the ia is not reliable i wanted to be sure that   the computation of the kl divergence is the correct procedure to adopt  to justify the approximation, because from google i did not find any example

Comment: One could interpret "product of univariate Gaussian pdf" as a multivariate Gaussian with a diagonal covariance matrix, in which case you are in the exact situation referenced in the thread.