# Compare similarity or difference of two distributions by the ratio of moments

Tags: distance, similarities

I'm looking for a measure that measure the similarity of two distributions in the following forms:
$$ 
S = \frac{a \mu_1 + b \sigma_1}{a \mu_2 + b \sigma_2}.
$$

The above formula I proposed is not rigorous. But it can show that if two distributions are similar, then $S$ would turn to 1. Does there exist a measure like this?

Comment: Hi Wynn! Welcome to CV. Have you considered a more general test of similarity such as the Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS) test?

Comment: make an assumption of the underlying distribution (maybe consider to test that hypothesis) and then use any distance for distributions, like KL divergence

Comment: Although your question is unclear (because you don't explain what this "similarity" is intended to mean or how it is to be applied), it is reminiscent of the [symmetrized divergence between two Normal distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66271).  Could you edit your post to help us understand the context of your question?