# Deriving the KL divergence loss for VAEs

Tags: kullback-leibler, autoencoders, variational-bayes

In a VAE, the encoder learns to output two vectors:

$$\mathbf{\mu} \in\ \mathbb{R}^{z}$$
$$\mathbf{\sigma} \in\ \mathbb{R}^{z}$$

which are the mean and variances for the latent vector $\mathbf{z}$, the latent vector $\mathbf{z}$ is then calculated by:

$$\mathbf{z} = \mu + \sigma \epsilon$$

where: $\epsilon = N(0, \mathbf{I}_{z \times z})$

The KL divergence loss for a VAE for a single sample is defined as (referenced from [this implementation](https://github.com/ethanluoyc/pytorch-vae/blob/master/vae.py) and [this explanation](http://kvfrans.com/variational-autoencoders-explained/)):

$$\frac{1}{2} \left[ \left(\sum_{i=1}^{z}\mu_{i}^{2} + \sum_{i=1}^{z}\sigma_{i}^{2} \right) - \sum_{i=1}^{z} \left(log(\sigma_{i}^{2}) + 1 \right) \right]$$

Though, I'm not sure how they got their results, would anyone care to explain or point me to the right resources?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The encoder distribution is $q(z|x)=\mathcal{N}(z|\mu(x),\Sigma(x))$ where $\Sigma=\text{diag}(\sigma_1^2,\ldots,\sigma^2_n)$.

The latent prior is given by $p(z)=\mathcal{N}(0,I)$.

Both are multivariate Gaussians of dimension $n$, for which in general the KL divergence is:
$$
\mathfrak{D}_\text{KL}[p_1\mid\mid p_2] =
\frac{1}{2}\left[\log\frac{|\Sigma_2|}{|\Sigma_1|} - n + \text{tr} \{ \Sigma_2^{-1}\Sigma_1 \} + (\mu_2 - \mu_1)^T \Sigma_2^{-1}(\mu_2 - \mu_1)\right]
$$
where $p_1 = \mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\Sigma_1)$ and $p_2 = \mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\Sigma_2)$.

In the VAE case, $p_1 = q(z|x)$ and $p_2=p(z)$, so $\mu_1=\mu$, $\Sigma_1 = \Sigma$, $\mu_2=\vec{0}$, $\Sigma_2=I$. Thus:
\begin{align}
\mathfrak{D}_\text{KL}[q(z|x)\mid\mid p(z)] 
&=
\frac{1}{2}\left[\log\frac{|\Sigma_2|}{|\Sigma_1|} - n + \text{tr} \{ \Sigma_2^{-1}\Sigma_1 \} + (\mu_2 - \mu_1)^T \Sigma_2^{-1}(\mu_2 - \mu_1)\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[\log\frac{|I|}{|\Sigma|} - n + \text{tr} \{ I^{-1}\Sigma \} + (\vec{0} - \mu)^T I^{-1}(\vec{0} - \mu)\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[-\log{|\Sigma|} - n + \text{tr} \{ \Sigma \} + \mu^T \mu\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[-\log\prod_i\sigma_i^2 - n + \sum_i\sigma_i^2 + \sum_i\mu^2_i\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[-\sum_i\log\sigma_i^2 - n + \sum_i\sigma_i^2 + \sum_i\mu^2_i\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[-\sum_i\left(\log\sigma_i^2 + 1\right) + \sum_i\sigma_i^2 + \sum_i\mu^2_i\right]\\
\end{align}

Comment: Can you comment on why this looks so different from the univariate case? (https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/7440/141343 bottom of question)

Comment: @BlackBear your univariate example doesn't assume $\sigma_2 = 1$, which is the only difference

Comment: @BlackBear as Firebug notes, $p$ is assumed to be multivariate standard normal (most of the time) in VAEs. If you set $n=1$ here and $\sigma_2=1,\,\mu_2=0$ there, they should match. Also, their answer starts from the definition of the KL divergence as an expectation of the log difference, whereas I started from the general expression for two Gaussians for simplicity.

Comment: What is $n$ in the equation? Why is it replaced with 1?

Comment: @GergőHorváth, $n$ is the dimension of the vector z. It is not replaced with 1, it is replaced with $\sum_{i=1}^n 1$.

Comment: Super, thanks. Would you have a reference to a derivation/proof of the KL divergence between 2 multivariate Gaussians?

Comment: My bad. Given here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60680/kl-divergence-between-two-multivariate-gaussians