# Understanding KL divergence between two univariate Gaussian distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, kullback-leibler

I'm trying to understand KL divergence from [this post on SE.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7440/kl-divergence-between-two-univariate-gaussians) I am following @ocram's answer, I understand the following :

$\int \left[\log( p(x)) - log( q(x)) \right] p(x) dx$

$=\int \left[ -\frac{1}{2} \log(2\pi) - \log(\sigma_1) - \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi) + \log(\sigma_2) + \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{x-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}\right)^2  \right] \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_1} \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}\right)^2\right] dx$

$=\int \left\{\log\left(\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}\right) + \frac{1}{2} \left[ \left(\frac{x-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}\right)^2 \right] \right\} \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_1} \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}\right)^2\right] dx$

But not the following:

$=E_{1} \left\{\log\left(\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}\right) + \frac{1}{2} \left[ \left(\frac{x-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}\right)^2 \right]\right\}$

$=\log\left(\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}\right) + \frac{1}{2\sigma_2^2} E_1 \left\{(X-\mu_2)^2\right\} - \frac{1}{2\sigma_1^2} E_1 \left\{(X-\mu_1)^2\right\}$

$=\log\left(\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}\right) + \frac{1}{2\sigma_2^2} E_1 \left\{(X-\mu_2)^2\right\} - \frac{1}{2}$

Now noting :
$(X - \mu_2)^2 = (X-\mu_1+\mu_1-\mu_2)^2 = (X-\mu_1)^2 + 2(X-\mu_1)(\mu_1-\mu_2) + (\mu_1-\mu_2)^2$

$=\log\left(\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}\right) + \frac{1}{2\sigma_2^2}
\left[E_1\left\{(X-\mu_1)^2\right\} + 2(\mu_1-\mu_2)E_1\left\{X-\mu_1\right\} + (\mu_1-\mu_2)^2\right] - \frac{1}{2}$

$=\log\left(\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}\right) + \frac{\sigma_1^2 + (\mu_1-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2} - \frac{1}{2}$

First off what is $E_1$?

Comment: E1 is the expectation with respect to the first distribution (p(x)). Denoting it with Ep would be better, I think.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I understand now. Just one confusion in the second last line of derivation, why is  $2(\mu_1-\mu_2)E_1\left\{X-\mu_1\right\}$ vanishing? @Ozan

Comment: Since $\mu_1$ is the mean of $X$, then the expectation of mean extracted $X$ which is  $E_1(X-\mu_1)$ becomes zero. So the term vanishes.

Comment: I thought in the same direction but felt it might be approximately zero. Anyway thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E_1$ is the expectation with respect to the first distribution $p(x)$. Denoting it with $E_p$ would be better, I think. – Monotros

---

I've created this answer from a comment so that this question is answered. [Better to have a short answer than no answer at
all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/)