# what is -0.5 in VAE loss function with KL term

Tags: loss-functions, autoencoders, kullback-leibler, mse, variational

The VAE loss is composed of two terms:

1. Reconstruction loss
2. KLD loss

in the implementation there is -0.5 applied to KLD loss. Kindly let me know what is this -0.5

Comment: The duplicate contains the essential details of the derivation.

Answer (score 0):

It's the (-1/2) taken out of the parentheses in KL divergence expression stated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7440/kl-divergence-between-two-univariate-gaussians). Basically, in VAE, $\mu_2=0,\sigma_2=1$. And, this expression is summed up for each latent dimension with $\mu_i, \sigma_i$.